# Where to store AWS credentials in ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS service, which requires AWS credentials. I use ECR to store docker images and jenkins visible only for VPN connections to build images.

I see 2 possibilities to provide AWS credentials to the service

1. Store them as Jenkins secret and insert into the docker image during build
2. Make them a part of the environment when creating ECS Task definition

What is more secure? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use an IAM role instead of hard-coded credentials? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, You should not use AWS credentials while working inside AWS, you should assign the [role to Task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) or services instead of passing the credentials to docker build or task definition.

> With IAM roles for Amazon ECS tasks, you can specify an IAM role that
>   can be used by the containers in a task. Applications must sign their
>   AWS API requests with AWS credentials, and this feature provides a
>   strategy for managing credentials for your applications to use,
>   similar to the way that Amazon EC2 instance profiles provide
>   credentials to EC2 instances

So sometimes the underlying application is not designed in a way that can use role so in this I will recommend storing ENV in the task definition but again from where to get the value of ENV?

Task definition support two methods to deal with ENV,

- Plain text as direct value
- Use ‘valueFrom’ attribute for ECS task definition

The following is a snippet of a task definition showing the format when referencing an [Systems Manager Parameter Store parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter/parameter_name"
    }]
  }]
}
```

This is the most secure and [recommended method by AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html) so this is the better way as compared to ENV in plain text inside Task definition or ENV in Dockerfile.

You can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html) and [systems-manager-parameter-store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

But to use these you will must provide permission to task definition to access systems-manager-parameter-store.